# Java recursion outputs name forwards and backwards

Tags: java, recursion

I wrote a basic recursion problem in class a long time ago and I'm trying to remember how I'm getting the output that prints.

Its basically prints out a name forwards and backwards.  I understand how it prints the name forwards but I'm clueless as to how it prints the name backwards.  I did a debug to see step by step what is going on but can't understand how index is decreasing after the name prints forwards.

```
public class CharRecursion 
{

public static void printName(String name, int index)
  {
    if(index > name.length() - 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(name.charAt(index));
        printName(name, index + 1);
        System.out.println(name.charAt(index));
    }
  }
public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
        printName("Brian", 0);
  }

}
```

The output is `BriannairB`

Comment: Look at the second `System.out.println` - it is being called after your recursion has reached the end.

Comment: In addition to Jaroslaw's comment, note that `index + 1` does not change the value of `index`. Thus, in the next line, the same character is printed.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand the second System.out.println is what is causing it but how is it that index is decreasing causing the letters to go backwards?  I must be missing something simple.

Answer (score 2):

The backwards part comes from the second `System.out.println(name.charAt(index));` statement.

This one is called only once the recursive call has ended, recursively, so you end up with the reverse String, look at the suffix markers :

```
    System.out.println(name.charAt(index) + " - ");
    printName(name, index + 1);
    System.out.println(name.charAt(index) + " * ");
```

You get :

```
B - 
r - 
i - 
a - 
n - 
n *
a *
i *
r *
B *
```

Since the actual sequence of calls is :

printName(name, 0) > printName(name, 1) > printName(name, 2) > printName(name, 3) > printName(name, 4)

The first call to resolve your second `println` statement will be `printName(name, 4)`, then `printName(name, 3)`, etc.. and the order of the printing becomes :

```
System.out.println(name.charAt(4) + " * ");
System.out.println(name.charAt(3) + " * ");
System.out.println(name.charAt(2) + " * ");
System.out.println(name.charAt(1) + " * ");
System.out.println(name.charAt(0) + " * ");
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to understand this is to step through it manually, using pen and paper. **I can't recommend strongly enough that you actually to this, physically, with real pieces of paper**, until you understand what's going on.

Use one sheet of paper to record output.

Use a new separate sheet of paper for each invocation of `printName()`.

Start at `main()`. When you see `printName("Brian", 0)`, that's a signal to start a new sheet of paper. At the top of the sheet, write the inputs: `name -
 "Brian", index = 0`.

Now you're in `printName()`, so go through it step by step. `0` is less than `"Brian".length() - 1`, so you can skip to the `else` block:

- `System.out.println(name.charAt(index));` - so write the result of `"Brian".charAt(0)`  on your output sheet: `B`.
- `printName(name, index + 1) -- since you're seeing`printName()`again, take another sheet of paper, write the inputs`name="Brian", index =  1` at the top, and **place this on top of the previous sheet**.

Keep working in this way, and you will keep adding to your stack of paper. This is directly analogous to the execution stack that Java maintains; this is the same stack that you see in a stacktrace.

Eventually you'll reach a point where `index = "Brian".length() -1`, so you return. When you see `return`, remove the sheet you're working on, screw it up and throw it in the bin. The runtime has finished with this invocation of the method. Continue with the sheet underneath, where you left off. You are now at the second `System.out.println(name.charAt(index));`. So write that character on your output sheet.

When you finish, you will find you have written "BriannairB" on your output sheet, and you should have a better understanding of recursion.

Each piece of paper represents a **stack frame**. Bear in mind:

- At a given moment during execution, only the topmost stack frame is "visible" as far as the execution is concerned.
- Local variables and parameters are stored in the stack frame. At some moment in your execution, the value of `index` in the current stack frame will be `3`. This has no effect on the value of `index` in the stack frame below -- that is a completely separate piece of storage, and will still be `2` when the `3` frame ends and is popped off the stack.

---

Once you get the hang of this, though, you can look at it at a more "declarative" level. What does `printName("Brian",0)` do?

It prints "B" then `printName("Brian", 1`) then "B".

I think this implementation is slightly easier to understand:

```
  void printName(String s) {
      if(s.length() > 0) {
           System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
           printName(s.substring(1));
           System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
      }
  }
```

So, `printName("Brian")` writes `B` then `printName("rian")` then `B`.

Or going from the deepest the stack will go:

`printName("")` writes nothing.

Therefore `printName("n")` writes `n` then `printName("")` then `n` -- which is `nn`.

Comment: OK!  Once you mentioned the stacktrace it started to click.  So basically the second println statement goes back through the stack and spits out whatever comes up next, which ends up being in reverse.  If I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: @BrianHogans I think your mental model of how program execution proceeds is a bit off. The a `println` statement doesn't "go through" anything. The JVM steps through the method statement-by-statement. When it encounters a method call, it adds to the stack, and puts everything else on hold while it deals with that method call. When it reaches the end of a method call, it removes that item from the stack and carries on where it left off. If you follow my advice and "run" it on paper, you are being the JVM.

Comment: Ok I'll definitely do that.  I want to make sure I get this conceptually before I move on to something different.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the execution sequence of your program. Program calls `printName("Brian",index)` function recursively which executes first `System.out.println(name.charAt(index));` before each call. When index reaches `5` function calls start returning and second `System.out.println(name.charAt(index));` is executed after each return.   [image]